# Redirect to main url from language subfolder url with TranslatePress

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I had added Translatepress to my website for multilanguage and have the option enabled (add subdirectory to url for languages). so the url was
mydomain.de/de
mydomain.de/en

Now i have removed the Translatepress but some trafic still comes with subdirectory /de/ or /en/
I wants to redirect all urls from /de/ or /en/ to main url (mydomain.de).

How can i do this with .htaccess or by other means ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried something, dont know if its good. but hope it will help some others.

So, the main language or my site is DE do, i redirected all links from /de/ to main url and from /en/ through 410

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^en/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R=410]
RewriteRule ^de/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R=301]
```

you can replace 410 with 301 if you wants to redirect /en/ to main url too.